# Apollo Optimistic UI update with different ID field name

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to make use of the optimistic update functionality of Apollo described in https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/optimistic-ui.html (in a React-Native app). Unfortunately as far as I can gather this only works if you are updating records which use a field named "id" as their primary key. Unfortunately I have many cases where that field has a different name. Is there any way I can tell Apollo to work with a different id field name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use apollo's `InMemoryCache` you can pass [dataIdFromObject](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates.html#normalization) that can return a value for an `id`, when initializing the cache. The default, that uses always the `id` would looks like this:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
});
```

To change this you can create a function that checks for the `.__typename` key in the incoming object to return the correct field according of the GraphQL type;

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: ({__typename, id, ...rest}) => {
    switch(__typename){
      case 'Foo': return rest.foo,
      case 'Bar': return rest.bar,
      default: return id,
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am using Apollo with AWS Appsync but this worked with its cacheOptions, thanks!